# Error con la función if utilizada en date_format de postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Buenos días.

Tengo la siguiente función en una query de Postgres:

```
date_format(
  if(("tblresoluciones"."medida_termino" = 'M'),
     ("tblresoluciones"."fecha_ini_vigencia" + ("tblresoluciones"."termino_vigencia" || 'month')::INTERVAL),
     ("tblresoluciones"."fecha_ini_vigencia" + ("tblresoluciones"."termino_vigencia" || 'year')::INTERVAL))
  ,'%d/%m/%Y') AS hasta
```

Al ejecutarla me encuentro con el siguiente error:

> [Err] ERROR:  la función if(boolean, timestamp without time zone,
>   timestamp without time zone) no es única LINE 7:
>   date_format(if(("tblresoluciones"."medida_termino" = 'M...
>                            ^ HINT:  No se pudo escoger la función más adecuada. Puede ser necesario agregar conversiones explícitas de
>   tipos.

Lo que he realizado es castear cada una de las columnas que son utilizadas en la función pero he conseguido el mismo resultado de error.

```
date_format(
  if(("tblresoluciones"."medida_termino" = 'M'),
     (("tblresoluciones"."fecha_ini_vigencia")::TIMESTAMP + ("tblresoluciones"."termino_vigencia" || 'month')::INTERVAL),
     (("tblresoluciones"."fecha_ini_vigencia")::TIMESTAMP + ("tblresoluciones"."termino_vigencia" || 'year')::INTERVAL))
  ,'%d/%m/%Y') AS hasta,
```

Agradeceria mucho su colaboración, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando de usar funciones de MySQL (`if`, `date_format`) en PostgreSQL. Cada base de datos tiene su propio sabor de SQL, por lo que es importante que te refieras a la documentación adecuada para tu base de datos.

En este caso, la condición que querías hacer con el `if` la puedes hacer mas bien con una expresión `CASE`, que es más estándar de todas maneras.

Y la sintaxis de MySQL que usas para formatear la fecha:

```
date_format(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

... equivale a la siguiente en PostgreSQL:

```
to_char(fecha, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

De modo que la expresión completa en PostgreSQL vendría siendo:

```
to_char(
  case when "tblresoluciones"."medida_termino" = 'M'
       then "tblresoluciones"."fecha_ini_vigencia"
            + ("tblresoluciones"."termino_vigencia" || ' month')::INTERVAL
       else "tblresoluciones"."fecha_ini_vigencia"
            + ("tblresoluciones"."termino_vigencia" || ' year')::INTERVAL
       end
  ,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS hasta
```

Comment: Esto funcionó para mi, te agradesco demaciado!